# Why the shape of header tank is the way it is?

Tags: rockets, tanks

The header tank is bulged out at the top and the bottom.What may be the reason for this?Can't simple cylinder tanks be used instead?[image]

Elon Musk also posted the [image](https://mobile.twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1247056590340947969?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Etweet) of Starship fuel header tank.

Comment: What in this image is a "header tank"? Most stages don't have them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple cylinder with flat circular sheets at both ends is less stable and would be heavier than a cylinder with hemispherical or elliptical ends.

A sphere has the best ratio of volume to surface and also of mass to volume. Material stress caused by internal pressure is homogenusly distributed over the surface.

If a sphere's diameter is too big for the rocket, a (short) cylinder with hemispheres at both ends is the second best optimal form. But for the cylindrical part stress in axial direction is only half of that in tangential (circumference) direction.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_vessel#Shape) and the [Kesselformel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kesselformel), only the german version has the essential formulas for axial and tangential tension.

Comment: @Auberron  To put it more simply-- a sphere is the most resistant to pressure of any shape.  See, for example, the info  at  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/is-a-circle-the-strongest-2d-shape-for-containing-internal-pressure

Comment: There is an english version of the page, it is linked in wikipedias sidebar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow%27s_formula

Comment: @Polygnome I know there is an english version too but the essential formulas for axial and tangential tension are missing.

Comment: @Polygnome  If you hit the "Translate this page" (at least in Chrome) is the output useable?